# Deploy jhipster on server with CentOS 7

Tags: server, jhipster, centos7

I'm trying to deploy my jhipster application on a server.

The server is an basic CentOS 7 distribution.

What should I install before deploying the war?

Apache, Tomcat, mySQL, anything else?

I'm not able to find a complete doc where to find how to set up a server from zero.

Comment: Here's the [Installation guide](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jhipster offers easy docker integration, so just use ist, and install docker on your server.

For docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/

If not:
For the war file you only need a javaRuntime and run it with java -jar your.jar

mysql only when you need it

Comment: When you talk about docker integration you refer to [this jhipster page](https://jhipster.github.io/docker-compose/)?
Do you know a good documentation on what it is and how it works? As I never worked with a docker before.

Comment: I added the docker doc in the answer. Its a pretty good documenation you fin everything you need